# Can I reset a form with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

is possible to use php to reset a form without refresh?
how can i archive this?

or is possible to do it with js?

most important is do it without to refresh the page and dont add another button for this(that's because the design)

any idea?
thanks
am working with recaptcha on my form and once i submitted the information i want to send a message
this is my js code

```
function validateCaptcha(){
    challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
    responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
    nameField = $("input#name").val();
    emailField = $("input#email").val();
    phoneField =$("input#phone").val();
    reasonField =$("select#reason").val();
    messageField =$("textarea#message").val();
    var html = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.recaptcha.php",
    data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField +"&name="+ nameField +"&email=" + emailField +"&phone="+ phoneField + "&reason=" + reasonField +"&message=" + messageField,
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    if(html == "success")
    {
        $("#captchaStatus").html("Success. Submitting form.");
        $("#thanks").html("Thank you, we going to keep in touch with you soon.  ");
        return false;

    }


    else
    {
        $("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again");
        Recaptcha.reload();
        return false;
    }
}
```

this is my php code

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $reason = $_POST['reason'];
    $message = $_POST['message'] ;

    if (empty($name)|| empty($email) || empty($message))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer (PRIVATEKEY, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
        if ($resp->is_valid) {

            $header = 'From: ' . $email . " \r\n";
            $msg = "Sent from: " . $name . "\r\n";
            $msg .= "Email: " . $email . " \r\n";
            $msg .= "Phone: " . $phone . " \r\n";
            $msg .= "Contact reason:" . $reason . " \r\n";
            $msg .= "Message: " . $message . " \r\n";

            $to = 'patricia@anetdesign.com';
            $subject = 'Emailmakers contact page';

            mail($to, $subject, utf8_decode($msg), $header);

             ?>success<?


        }
        else 
        {
        die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
           "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, once you sed the ajax request if the captcha fails then just reload the entire form.

Say you have only the form in myform.php and you include it in your main page, when the captcha does not match you can just reload the form. Like this:

```
if (html != "Success")
{
     $("#divThatHoldsTheForm").html(html)
}
```

and in your myform.php you have only:

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
  <!-- some inputs -->
</form>
```

Comment: only problem now is that $("#divThatHoldsTheForm").html(html)
 hides the completely form! but i really think is way to go!! thank you very much! i have been trying lot of ways to do it.. maybe using some .replace() or so right?

Comment: well, the purpose to use ("#divThatHolsTheForm").html(html) is to replace the form with a new form, so I did not get the point why you should use a .replace() again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `reset()` function. If you have a form named `frm` then use can use `frm.reset()`.
Or just write code to first get all textboxes and set its `value` attribute to `""`. this wont need to refresh your page

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP mean refreshing the page (only in case of ajax) so i suggest you try to use javascript instead of php to this task